# Javascript: true and false comparisons with 0 and 1 numbers

Tags: javascript

When working with ajax requests, if a response property is either 1 (type: number) for true or 0 (type: number) for false,
what is the best way to check if this is true. All of these examples work, just wondering if there is a preferred one to use and the reason it is preferred.

```
if (response.hasOwnProperty('test')) {

    // 1
    if (response.test === 1) {
        alert('is true');
    }

    // 2
    if (response.test) {
        alert('is true');
    }

    // 3
    if (response.test == true) {
        alert('is true');
    }

    // 4
    if (Boolean(response.test) === true) {
        alert('is true');
    }

    // 5
    if (response.test == 1) {
        alert('is true');
    }
}
```

Comment: This is opinion-based. Take the one that fit well in your code and keep this logic for the other conditions

Comment: Best to always use strict equality comparison when possible IMO: number 1. Number 4 will pass when `.test` is truthy, but something other than 1, which may lead to unexpected results.

Comment: I'd go with the 1st one, so that it's pretty clear and you fail fast in the future if the response changes.

Comment: AJAX requests usually follow a protocol which defines the types of the various values, so in these cases it's often better to check strict equality. For example, if the `response` object doesn't have a member called `test` at all due to an error, then `if (alert.test)` will simply evaluate to false, which might be misleading.

Comment: I suggest the 1st one too, clear and concise

Comment: @MátéSafranka, where do i find this protocol?

Comment: @NinaScholz I don't mean like one specific protocol, I mean each webservice usually defines its own protocol that specifies the format of the requests and responses.

Comment: `response.hasOwnProperty('test')`  Not sure why you need this, no matter what option you pick..

Comment: @Keith D'oh, I skipped that line when I read the post... kind of invalidates part of my comment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was said, it's mostly opinion based.

However, there are some pro and cons depends by the approach you're using.

First of all, the context is important: if it's code you're writing for yourself or it's a project with other developers that are collaborating; if you also wrote - and therefore you have control - on the backend, and so on.

In general, if it's something I've control AND it's not a production code, I would probably go for the second form: quick enough, clear enough - it's truthy or falsy - and I'm sure that the value returned from the backend are 0 and 1 for a reason.

In all the other scenario, I would go for the strict equal, so the first form: it's more explicit. Reading the second form, the only thing I know is that the value can be truthy or falsy, I've no idea what the actual value can be. If there is any change in the API - because, for instance, I do not have direct control on it, or maybe someone else change it in the project and forgot this piece of code - the code would fail. For example:

```
if (response.test === 1) {
  // do something
} else if (response.test === 0) {
  // do something else or do nothing
} else {
  throw new Error("Unexpected value from response.test")
}
```

Even if you don't have the `else` would be safe enough if the API would add a new value. For example, let's say that now the API can returns 0, 1, or 3. If you check for truthy values, 1 and 3 will be equals. But if you have:

```
if (response.test === 1) {
  // do something
} else if (response.test === 0) {
  // do something else or do nothing
}
```

You're good; your code will still works as intended, even if the API is extended.